# Pendant lights without a ceiling box

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, new-home

I am having a house built, and I noticed there was no exposed ceiling box at the locations of my pendant lights.  I was unable to get out there to visually verify things before drywall went up (that's why there's a construction manager) The CM reassures me everything is wired, inspection passed, and ready to be pulled through on the final set out.

I walked through the attic this morning to find nothing more than a bundle of romex hanging from a roof truss, coming from the light switch location.

I've never seen a new construction rough in without a ceiling box for each light fixture, and this includes other houses this CM is building.

Is this cause for concern?  Should I require another electrical inspection for this? The attic will be blown in, concealing anything wrong, for the final inspection.

Comment: It is not a concern as far as the task can be completed. It is a concern in that the contractor or the sub-contractor is possibly not doing a complete job.

Answer (score 2):

If they did not use boxes I would consider this a code violation unless they used romex splices , the splices can be made without a box romex to romex other than that I would take a photo of the point of connection and post it but it sounds shady to me. In the states I have worked to get a rough inspection signed off for cover all the boxes need to be in place.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly that they will be putting the boxes in, old work boxes, at the time of the lights to ensure the lights align correctly to what they will be lighting.